# iOS 5 setup freezing at set up email

Tags: ios

I am trying to update my iPad first generation to iOS 5. It is freezing at the "Set Up Email" screen after I enter my email address and password. I have already clicked on the link in the email that asked me to verify my contact email address. Any thoughts on how to get past this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to update my 1st Gen iPad to iOS5. I would begin by shutting down the iPad and rebooting it. Make sure that all your apps are closed out and then try the upgrade again.